Is there a way to install ubuntu without usb/cd directly from a hard drive
I want to install ubuntu alongside on my pc which has windows on a separate drive. Is there any way to do this without usb/cd as I do not have any spare

A duplicate of 121212 or 340156

Does this answer your question? Install Ubuntu from ISO image directly from hard disk of a system running Linux?

You can use UNetbootin to make boot entry with Ubuntu ISO file from your hard disk


This program does not show the drive I want to install it to

this program will help you to boot by  Ubuntu live system, after then you can install Ubuntu on any drive

Thank you this appears to have worked
